# What happens when I run the Glue Crawler again without any change in the files in S3 path it pointed to?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I run a AWS Crawler once. Again I run the same Crawler. What is the difference first and second time?

When I the Run same AWS Crawler gain without any change in the files in S3, will it crawl all the files gain?

Sometime I may have 500 files in the bucket. Will Crawler process all the files or it does nothing as the files are not modified and no new files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html)

If your crawler runs more than once, perhaps on a schedule, it looks for new or changed files or tables in your data store. The output of the crawler includes new tables and partitions found since a previous run.

I imagine that it has a mechanism to track S3 file changes using modification date of files.